# Update DB relationship via Controller Method (Entity)

Tags: c#, .net, entity

Trying to update a many to many relationship in my database that looks like this:

```
DeckCards
    (key sign) Deck_id
    (key sign) Card_id
```

I am trying to do this via my controller Action:

```
    public ViewResult Add(int id)
    {
        var cardInDb = _context.Cards.Single(c => c.Id == id);

        var deckInDb = _context.Decks.Single(d => d.id == id);

        deckInDb.Card.Add(cardInDb);
        cardInDb.Deck.Add(deckInDb);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

My View:

```
@model YGOBuilder.Models.ViewModels.DeckCardViewModel

<div>
    <h4>DeckCardViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cards.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.Atk)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cards.Atk)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.Def)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cards.Def)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.Desc)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cards.Desc)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.Level)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cards.Level)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.Type)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cards.Type)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cards.Attribute)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cards.Attribute)
        </dd>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Cards.Card_Images)
        {

            <dd>
                <img src=@item.image_url height="300" width="200" style="margin: 2px">
            </dd>

        }

    </dl>


    @foreach (var d in Model.Decks)
    {
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        @Html.ActionLink($"Add to: {d.Name} ", "Add", new { id = d.id })
    </ul>
    }


</div>
```

The end result I'm looking for is the database table being updating the DeckCards Table like so:

```
Deck_Id     Card_Id
    3            1
```

Card with the ID of 1, is mapped to Deck 3.

My models:

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Atk { get; set; }
    public int? Def { get; set; }
    public string Desc {get; set;}
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public virtual List<Image> Card_Images { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Deck> Deck { get; set; }


}

public class Deck
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Card")]
    public virtual List<Card> Card { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the above code,  var cardInDb = _context.Cards.Single(c => c.Id == id); seemed to break with a Sequence contains no elements error.

Comment: Add a Where checking for Card != null : _context.Cards.Where(c => c != null).Single(c => c.Id == id);

Comment: @jdweng still the same error at var cardInDb = _context.Cards.Where(c => c != null).Single(c => c.Id == id);  Sequence contains no elements error.

Comment: Try : DBNull.Value instead of null

Comment: @jdweng that doesnt seem to be accepted, throws 'DBNull' is a type, which is not valid in the given context' error

Comment: Did you leave off the .Value?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get card with ID of deck. You need to pass DeckId and CardId to Add method from view and use them to get Card and Deck.

**Updated**

You need to do something like that:

```
@Html.ActionLink($"Add to: {d.Name} ", "Add", new { cardId = Model.Cards.Id, deckId = d.id })
```

...

```
public ViewResult Add(int cardId, int deckId)
{
    var cardInDb = _context.Cards.Single(c => c.Id == cardId);

    var deckInDb = _context.Decks.Single(d => d.id == deckId);

    deckInDb.Card.Add(cardInDb);
    cardInDb.Deck.Add(deckInDb);

    return View("Index");
}
```

Also don't forget to save your changes after you are adding items.

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you Igor? Can you provide a snippet to help me understand?

Comment: Hi thanks for your snippets, but that doesnt seem to work. It brings up this error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Add(Int32)' in 'YGOBuilder.Controllers.CardController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters